# GridView Paging Problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, paging

I have a gridview that is set up to do paging but it is not working correctly.

Only the first page's control is visible - the other pages have boxes rendered but no control inside them.

Does anyone know why this may be? I have checked that I have more than one page of data.

Thanks,

Oliver

I have attached a screenshot which I hope illustrates my problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOFnB.jpg

EDIT: source for the gridview

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
    CssClass="GridView1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView_SelectedIndexChanged"
    AllowPaging="True" PageSize="20">      
    <selectedrowstyle backcolor="LightCyan" forecolor="DarkBlue" font-bold="true" />
</asp:GridView>
```

it is populated using a dataset generated in c#

EDIT: c# codebehind

```
    protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        bindGridView();
    }

    public void bindGridView()
    {
        //declare the connection string to use
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        //create sql connection
        SqlConnection mySQLconnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        //open connection
        mySQLconnection.Open();

            //define command using text string
            SqlCommand mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlTester, mySQLconnection);
            SqlDataAdapter mySqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(mySqlCommand);

            //create dataset to fill gridview with
            DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
            mySqlAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);

            //fill gridview
            GridView1.DataSource = myDataSet;
            GridView1.DataBind();

        //close the sql connection
        mySQLconnection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Could you perhaps show the code you use to bind the dataset to your gridview as well?

Comment: Oh, and are you by any chance handling the PageIndexChanged event?

Comment: Have you checked the source code? Are the numbers not appearing in there either? I'm wondering whether its a CSS issue with non-selected page numbers.

Comment: there you go - my dataset is created using a string sqlTester

and i have some code that hopefully handles the pageindexchanging event - should i be handling the pageindexchanged event instead?

Comment: @curt i've had a look and it seems to be generating - there are 10 rows which each have a href link

Comment: could U write `OnPageIndexChanging`event , How u handle it?

Comment: OnPageIndexChanging calls "GridView1_PageIndexChanging" which is in the codebehind

Comment: Nothing wrong in that you set `PageSize="20"` and it is displaying `20` try changing it to `5` or `10` and have a look

Comment: How and when (in the page lifecycle) are you populating the red footer text that indicates how many pages are in the grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think according to your `aspx` and your `.cs`. there is some problem in your css file"`GridView1`".Try to remove the css class and tell us . is the problem still exist or not.

Note:

It's not related to your question. but i think you should separate your code in layers instead of writing all the code in your page code behind.

Read about:

- Layering in asp.net.
- ORM.

Comment: Removing the css class worked! I guess I will just try to work little bits back in and try to work out where I messed up.

Thanks for the tips - I'll have a look at layering

Comment: You are welcome,try to fix the problems in the CSS file.and feel free to sign it as an answer , if it helps u.thanks :)

Comment: got it now - i had another piece of unused css floating around that was messing things up...

Comment: With my pleasure.I'm glad u get it.

Answer (score 0):

You are making connection and database trip on each page index change event. It causes lot of overhead. Try this.

```
public void bindGridView()
{
    //declare the connection string to use
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    //create sql connection
    SqlConnection mySQLconnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    //open connection
    mySQLconnection.Open();

        //define command using text string
        SqlCommand mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlTester, mySQLconnection);
        SqlDataAdapter mySqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(mySqlCommand);

        //create dataset to fill gridview with
        DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
        mySqlAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);

        //fill gridview
        GridView1.DataSource = myDataSet;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        viewstate.add("myDataSet",myDataSet);

    //close the sql connection
    mySQLconnection.Close();
}
```

In page index change event, do this...
    protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        GridView.datasource=(DataTable)ViewState["myDataSet");
        GridView.DataBind();
    }

Use session if viewstate gives some error regarding serialization. This will make your code more efficient and optimized.

Comment: Thanks for this, I can see how that would make things more efficient - I will try and work it in :)